# Show that the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 16 can be arranged in a line so that the sum of any of two neighbors is a square.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Ex.: 8, 1, 15, 10, 6, 3, 13, 12, 4, 5, 11, 14, 2, 7, 9, 16

The sums are: 9, 16, 25, 16, ...

In fact I want to know for which numbers N the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., N has this property.

Maybe the sum not being a square but a cube or k-th power, or maybe arranging in a circle...

Is there any sequence of N's on oeis or something?

Comment: Here is the video to better understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_vN6z9fLbk

Comment: Here's another video, focusing on a graph theory approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY